# running a python script on many files

Tags: python, shell

I have a set of files `aaa_cntrl.txt`, `bbb_cntrl.txt`,....`zzz_cntrl.txt`. I want to run a python script script.py on each of these files and produce output `aaa_out.txt`,`bbb_out.txt`,....`zzz_out.txt`.

my python script is

```
import sys
file_in = sys.argv[0]
file_out = sys.argv[1]
print "This is the input file", file_in
print "This is the output file", file_out
```

Command line is `python script.py aaa_cntrl.txt aaa_out.txt`

But I want to automatically specifiy the input as `*_cntrl.txt` and get the output as `*_out.txt`.
How do I do this?

Comment: `argv[0]` gives the **name of the script**...

Comment: Furthermore mind that if you write `*_cntrl.txt` the **shell** will perform the expansion. So Python only sees `python script.py aaa_cntrl.txt bbb_cntrl.txt ...`.

Comment: As to how you do it, shell globbing or `find` will handle these for you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop over all input files and determine the output name inside the script then as your shell (at least on linux / unix) will expand the wildcard for you.

```
import sys

for file_in in sys.argv[1:]:
    # probably some more reliable way is required here in production
    file_out = file_in.split('_', 1)[0] + '_out.txt'

    print "This is the input file", file_in
    print "This is the output file", file_out
```

Answer (score 0):

I've just done that a couple of day ago using `argparse`.

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('files', nargs='+')
args = parser.parse_args()

for f in args.files:
    process(f)
```

Then, just have to call your script with `./myscript.py *_cntrl.txt`, and your shell will perform the expansion, as pointed out by Willem Van Onsem in the comments.
You can also take a look at the `argparse.FileType` to improve this code.

If your files names are well formated, I suggest you to automatically create the name of your output file depending on the input file. 
I mean, if `xxx_cntrl.txt` is always transformed into `xxx_out.txt`, you can simply do `file_out = file_in.replace("cntrl", "out")`.

Otherwise, you can do something like

```
parser.add_argument('files', nargs='+')
parser.add_argument('-o', nargs='+')
args = parser.parse_args()

for in_file, out_file in zip(args.file, args.o):
    process(in_file, out_file)
```

Anyway, I really recommend you the `argparse` module instead of a manual parsing of `sys.argv`.

Comment: If someone can provide me a hint about the downvote, I'll be glad to improve my answer :)